# Issue filtering by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, alteryx

I am attempting to filter for dates (using alteryx in db tools) from a column called `Date_of_Pay` that is currently a string in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I have tried the following:

```
select table.*
from table
where cast(Date_of_Pay AS date) >= '20140101' AND cast(Date_of_Pay AS date) <= '20141231'
-- alternatively I have tried 
-- where convert(date, Date_of_Pay, 101) >= '20140101' AND convert(date, Date_of_Pay, 101) <= '20141231'
```

and am getting an error:

> Error ReadRecord: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have also compared to the string `01/01/2014` and many other combinations and cannot seem to find the right way. Both of the ways above work on one table but it does not work on the other table that it will later be unioned with. I was thinking it might be something wrong with the data in the second table but I was hoping someone might have more insight.

Comment: You'd have to show us some sample data in order for us to give any insight. However there is loads of information out there about the converting dates to and from strings... you don't have to look very far to find what you need. The official docs are always a good starting point. As is storing your dates as a date datatype instead of a string.

Comment: Also, is Alteryx really a relevant tag for this question?

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format, so it can't be stored in one; they are stored as binary values. *If* you're storing as a `varchar`, however, you have a huge problem and need to fix your design. Stores dates as a `date`, there is no better data type, and a `varchar` is by far the worst. I can assure you that 04 January 2010 is not after 01 December 2020, but it is according to the data you describe.

Comment: Can't show data bc it's for work, also did not create the table and I am fairly new to the company and haven't worked w/databases before this so I don't think I can change it. So yeah I'm having issues with exactly that '04 January 2010 is not after 01 December 2020, but it is according to the data you describe.'

Comment: @kakas11 you don't show *actual* data, you create a small test query which demonstrates the problem. And anyway, given you are mostly interested in the date column thats hardly sensitive information so long as you don't include columns which are sensitive.

Comment: @kakas11, it makes sense you cannot modify the table.  However, a workaround here is to try to reproduce the problem creating sample table (in a database you can play with) with the exact column types as the data in question.  The suggestions of the other commenters above about reviewing the technical documentation about data types for your db is also a good idea.  Also, you tagged this as an "Alteryx" question... is the data stored in Alteryx or is it displayed/reported there?

Comment: @kakas11 because ***if*** you *really* are storing dates in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` in your database that means your storing them as a `(n)varchar`, and a `varchar` like `'12/01/2010'` is **greater than** `'04/01/2020'`. Therefore "`'12/01/2010'`" is **after** "`'04/01/2020'`".

Answer (score 0):

Both side in the where condition should have the same data type.

You could convert both to date like this:

```
Select table.*
from table
where convert(date,Date_of_Pay,101) = convert(date,’20140101’,112)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the ask in a table that stores [Date_of_Pay] char in the format of MM/dd/yyyy. Small point, your question has a mistake in that mm is minutes not months. I used the Connect In-DB tool using the following query. I made sure to check the query in SSMS first!

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table
WHERE CAST(Date_of_Pay AS DATE) >= '20140101'
AND CAST(Date_of_Pay AS DATE) <= '20141231'
```

I do not receive any such errors as you did. Please troubleshoot this in SSMS or however else you query outside of Alteryx. If the query works and returns the expected values, then paste it in Alteryx. I suspect, as others have mentioned in the comments, that the issue lies with the data in the tables.

I recreated the ask using Alteryx 2020.1.5.25447 and
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 18363: ) (Hypervisor).

RECAP: test your query on the tables directly, outside of Alteryx. You will definitely get that error. Fix there and only then paste into Alteryx.